# How do I properly ignore my base objects?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Every time I try and allow Fluent NHibernate automap my domain model I
get the following error...

The entity 'BaseObject' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method
to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).

My domain model looks something like this...

```
Customer   (Assembly #1)
 CoreEntity   (Assembly #1)
     EntityWithTypeId<Guid>   (Assembly #2)
        BaseObject   (Assembly #2)
```

The only work around I've found is to call the following..

```
.IgnoreBase<BaseObject>()
.IgnoreBase<CoreEntity>()
```

Is there a better way than using IgnoreBase? Maybe in a convention or
in the DefaultAutomappingConfiguration?

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

On a global scale I've found there is no way to handle situations by creating schemas. For now I've created a pre-process for unique database setup. If anyone has any ideas, I'm open to them.